# Is there a Standard way of verifying the token the user has whenever they use a React application?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

```
  
    function App() {

    return (
      <>
        <div>
        <InitUser/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />}/>
          </Routes>
        </div> 
      </>
    )
    }

   function InitUser(){
      const navigate=useNavigate();
      useEffect(()=>{
      const init=async()=>{
       const token=localStorage.getItem('token');
     console.log("Inside init");
     if(!token){
        navigate("/login");
        return;
     }
     let response;
     try{
      response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/auth/me",{
      headers:{
        'token':'Bearer '+token
      }
    });
     }catch(e){
       localStorage.removeItem('token');
        navigate("/login");
    }
    const {status}=response?.data;
     if(!status){
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      navigate("/login")
    }
    }

     init();
   },[]);

   return(
    <div></div>
   )
}

export default App
```

Is this the right way of doing things in React? I also thought of using a store and checking it everytime i load a page, but that seems odd I would be repeating code. From the articles i have read they suggested a ContextProvider but still end up writing the same code on every page. So is there a standard  way of solving this in React?